# Notifying an admin of a new registration using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

All of my users will be unapproved until they are approved by an admin, the admin will be logging into the site to mark the user as approved. I am following the [Devise docs here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in) which is working out great but how do I send an email to the admin once a new user has signed up so that the admin is aware and can approve the sign up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about in your User model, do something like this:

```
after_create :send_admin_mail
def send_admin_mail
   ###Send email stuff here
end
```

You may want to use [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

There may be some built in Devise way, but I can't find anything. This basically just sends an alert to you.

Comment: I could not find anything within Devise but i also couldn't find the "Require admin to activate account before sign_in" docs either so I thought it's worth asking. None the less, thanks. I used the after_create callback.

Comment: JeffC:  sorry, what do you mean 'I could not find anything within Devise but i also couldn't find the "Require admin to activate account before sign_in" docs either so I thought it's worth asking' - i.e., you have the link to the "`Devise docs here`" up above in your question - sorry, just want to make sure that I'm not missing something... I'm doing the same thing but having an issue with  ActionMailer

Comment: I would like to know how to do it as well. I don't think it is a good idea to send emails from model callback though. It adds another concern to the model class and it may cause troubles when you create users from console (e.g. seeding or development) or in testing.

Answer (score 0):

**As of 2020**

The docs have been updated to answer this question [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in#email-notifications). Of course feel free to modify to your needs.

Summary:

After running `rails g mailer AdminMailer`. Modify `app/mailers/admin_mailer.rb` to the following:

```
class AdminMailer < Devise::Mailer
    default from: 'from@example.com'
    layout 'mailer'

    def new_user_waiting_for_approval(email)
      @email = email
      mail(to: 'admin@email.com', subject: 'New User Awaiting Admin Approval')
    end
  end
```

Then update `app/models/user.rb` to:

```
  after_create :send_admin_mail
  def send_admin_mail
    AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(email).deliver
  end
```

Lastly, modify the following to your needs `views/admin_mailer/new_user_waiting_for_approval.erb`.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks to the both of you for your feedback. I've added the summary as well as the link.